# ERC-20 Token Transfer Failed

Tags: transactions, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-20, contract-debugging

I am trying to transfer ERC-20 Token Senderon (SDRN) from my Senderon wallet to any other Ethereum wallet address.

When I try to do this it fails and has the following message:
"Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Out of gas] 
The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender"

I have tried many times (even with a gas price of 100) and it does not work.

TX HASH: 0x5ed0838be237e0fce23bc98f7410073e908d8f27f31d61344746d2239e076891
Link: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5ed0838be237e0fce23bc98f7410073e908d8f27f31d61344746d2239e076891

Also, when I try to use their online wallet which is very similar to their desktop wallet, I get another error.

This time it says success but it also says:
"The ERC-20 Token Transfer might have Failed (ErrCode: unable to locate corresponding Transfer event log), check with sender"

TX HASH: 0x2febf4c4016aa4d7890bfb55e5b564eceaacdef77dd9ed469765e5141eeb7620
LINK: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2febf4c4016aa4d7890bfb55e5b564eceaacdef77dd9ed469765e5141eeb7620

**Please note: When I transfer these SDRN tokens from cryptopia or myether wallet, I have no problems. So it looks like there is some problem with the Senderon wallet, I just don't know what it is. This is a very small project and this is the first release of the wallet (sort of like a beta).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I need to move these funds ASAP.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

50k is obviously too strict limit, when transferring to new account - you need 20k gas to write the new account balance, plus 21k for transaction itself plus whatever else the code do. Zeppelin ERC20 transfers to new account cost ~54k gas.

Comment: Thanks so much for the information. How do I increase the gas limit? It seems by default that the wallet uses a limit of 50k. So I am not sure how t decrease it

Comment: I can't see it on senderon web wallet, seems to me like a bug in the webwallet implementation. I can not also see the possibility to export keys, so only option remaining is to contact their support.